# How to delete multiple buffers in Vim?

Tags: vim, buffer

Assuming I have multiple files opened as buffers in Vim. The files have `*.cpp`, `*.h` and some are `*.xml`. I want to close all the XML files with `:bd *.xml`. However, Vim does not allow this (E93: More than one match...).

Is there any way to do this?

P.S. I know that `:bd file1 file2 file3` works. So can I somehow evaluate `*.xml` to `file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml`?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

You can use `<C-a>` to complete all matches. So if you type `:bd *.xml` and then hit `<C-a>`, vim will complete the command to `:bd file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml`.

Comment: @Florian `<tab>` only allows you to cycle through the matches, putting a single entry on the command line, `<C-a>` adds all matches at once.

Comment: my god you're right! sorry. tab just works when there is only one possible result.

Comment: How do you use <C-a> with vim on tmux?

Comment: tmux doesn't bind <C-a> by default, but if you configured it to e.g. use <C-a> instead of <C-b> to emulate screen, you should also configure it to map, for example, <C-a>a to pass a <C-a> through to the program running inside tmux. The screen-keys.conf that comes with tmux does that.

Comment: JFTR, in case you have [`vim-rsi`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi) installed (I think, it's a must have for everyone on \*nix), to get the `<C-a>` work the original way in the command line, you should use `<C-x>` `<C-a>` instead.

Comment: A way to pass the <C-a> to vim from tmux is press <C-a>:send-prefix.
That way vim will receive the <C-a>

Comment: Is there an undo version of `<C-A>`? Say I've got `*/config*` and hit `<C-A>`, is there a way to return to `*/config/*` instead of all the matches? Would help finding the right paths to use. `<C-d>` is at least a preview, so that'll work in a pinch

Answer (score 67):

```
:3,5bd[elete]
```

Will delete buffer range from 3 to 5 .

Comment: If you want to delete single buffers such as 3 and 5, use `:bd 3 5`.

Answer (score 26):

You also can use alternatively use:

```
    :.,$-bd[elete]    " to delete buffers from the current one to last but one
    :%bd[elete]       " to delete all buffers
```

Comment: This works nice.
I do a *:ls* to see buffer numbers and them *:a,bbd* to delete buffers from number a to b

Answer (score 8):

You can use this.

```
:exe 'bd '. join(filter(map(copy(range(1, bufnr('$'))), 'bufname(v:val)'), 'v:val =~ "\.xml$"'), ' ')
```

It should be quite easy to add it to a command.

```
function! s:BDExt(ext)
  let buffers = filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val) && bufname(v:val) =~ "\.'.a:ext.'$"')
  if empty(buffers) |throw "no *.".a:ext." buffer" | endif
  exe 'bd '.join(buffers, ' ')
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 BDExt :call s:BDExt(<f-args>)
```

Comment: I know next to nothing about Vimscript, but how about glob() function?

Comment: `glob()` will only give you existing files (on your hard drive), and not opened buffers.

Comment: You forgot to `fnameescape()` buffer names.

Comment: I've just checked with `c:/Program files/foo.bar`, and even `foo.bar.foo` and it worked perfectly. `fnameescape()` may have been required if I used the buffer names. But I'm only checking whether the buffer names match a given expression: `\.{ext}$` -- I give buffer numbers to :bd`. I don't any reason to escape anything for regex matching.

Answer (score 5):

Try the script below. The example is for "txt", change it as needed, e.g. to "xml".
Modified buffers are not deleted. Press \bd to delete the buffers.

```
map <Leader>bd :bufdo call <SID>DeleteBufferByExtension("txt")

function!  <SID>DeleteBufferByExtension(strExt)
   if (matchstr(bufname("%"), ".".a:strExt."$") == ".".a:strExt )
      if (! &modified)
         bd
      endif
   endif
endfunction
```

**[Edit]**
Same without :bufdo (as requested by Luc Hermitte, see comment below)

```
map <Leader>bd :call <SID>DeleteBufferByExtension("txt")

function!  <SID>DeleteBufferByExtension(strExt)
   let s:bufNr = bufnr("$")
   while s:bufNr > 0
       if buflisted(s:bufNr)
           if (matchstr(bufname(s:bufNr), ".".a:strExt."$") == ".".a:strExt )
              if getbufvar(s:bufNr, '&modified') == 0
                 execute "bd ".s:bufNr
              endif
           endif
       endif
       let s:bufNr = s:bufNr-1
   endwhile
endfunction
```

Comment: I don't like `:bufdo` as it messes the current window.

Answer (score 4):

> `TAB` will only autocomplete one file for you as of Vim 7.4.282
>    use `<c-a>` to autocomplete all files.

You can just use:

```
bd filetype
```

then just use `<c-a>` to facilitate the completion of all open files of specified filetype.

for example, you have 1.xml, 2.xml, 3.xml, and 4.xml, 
you can do:

```
bd xml
```

then press `<c-a>`

vim will autocomplete for you as follow:

```
bd 1.xml 2.xml 3.xml 4.xml
```

you can just press enter to complete the command.

if you have made changes in one of the files mentioned above, do remember to do:

```
bd! xml
```

Answer (score 3):

I too had a need for this functionality all the time.  This is the solution I have in my vimrc.

```
function! GetBufferList()
    return filter(range(1,bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')
endfunction

function! GetMatchingBuffers(pattern)
    return filter(GetBufferList(), 'bufname(v:val) =~ a:pattern')
endfunction

function! WipeMatchingBuffers(pattern)
    let l:matchList = GetMatchingBuffers(a:pattern)

    let l:count = len(l:matchList)
    if l:count < 1
        echo 'No buffers found matching pattern ' . a:pattern
        return
    endif

    if l:count == 1
        let l:suffix = ''
    else
        let l:suffix = 's'
    endif

    exec 'bw ' . join(l:matchList, ' ')

    echo 'Wiped ' . l:count . ' buffer' . l:suffix . '.'
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 BW call WipeMatchingBuffers('<args>')
```

Now, I can just do `:BW regex` (e.g. `:BW \.cpp$` and wipe all matching buffers that have match that pattern in their pathname.

If you want to delete rather than wipe, you can of course replace `exec 'bw ' . join(l:matchList, ' ')` with `exec 'bd ' . join(l:matchList, ' ')`

Comment: I sometimes wonder why vim doesn't support regular expressions everywhere (`:badd`, `:bdelete`, `:bufdo`, `:bn`...)

Answer (score 2):

Very simply: use the `:bd[elete]` command.  For example, `:bd[elete] buf#1 buf#5 buf#3` will delete the buffers 1, 3, and 5.