# Leave Diff view with Fugitive

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

With vim-fugitive,

is there an easy way to "unsplit" and `:Gedit` (return to the current object in the working tree)?

E.g. when in `Gcommit`/`Gstatus` buffers, you would press <kbd>D</kbd> to enter side-by-side diff. 
Now, pressing <kbd>ZZ</kbd> would just leave me with a single editor, viewing the `fugitive://` side...

To get back to single editor (with the working-tree version I have to do

> <kbd>ZZ</kbd><kbd>:Gedit</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

(or ZZZZ to close both sides).

I'd like to have something like `gq` as documented under `Gblame`:

```
        q     close blame and return to blamed window
        gq    q, then |:Gedit| to return to work tree version
```

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested by Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/36) you can simply close the other window with `<C-W><C-O>`.

Comment: That would also close the status view, if you started from there: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XWowq.png (I'd like to "zap" the LHS of the diff panes, but keep the rest)

Comment: I don't think you have an easy way out on that :S

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess I'll have to simply `nnoremap g<C-q> ZZ:Gedit<CR>` then