# Return from Gdiffsplit! three-way view

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

When I get a merge conflict, I do:

```
:Gvdiffsplit!
```

which opens a three-way diff to allow me to choose between "ours" and "theirs" for each chunk.

Once I've done whatever I need to do, how do I close this view and return to just viewing the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you exit vimdiff mode in vim, specifically, for Fugitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703644/how-do-you-exit-vimdiff-mode-in-vim-specifically-for-fugitive)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7762613/2071807) solves my problem. Use `Ctrl-w Ctrl-o` for "make this window the only one".